# Regex capturing group terminating early

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I don't usually ask dumb regex questions. But here's one for the regex vultures....

Take these strings...

```
-This is nice (show cow)
*This (or that) (show mouse)
-Whatever
-Hiya (everyone)
```

All these should be a match. ie Lead with `*` or `-`, then any text, then can conditionally be followed by whitespace and `(show xxx)` where `xxx` can be any text. I want these captured separately ie...

```
-This is nice (show cow)
   Match 1 : 'This is nice'
   Match 2 : '(show cow)' or just 'cow'

*This (or that) (show mouse)
   Match 1 : 'This (or that)'
   Match 2 : 'show mouse' or just 'mouse'

-Whatever
   Match 1 : 'Whatever'

-Hiya (everyone)
   Match 1 : 'Hiya (everyone)'

+Hello
   No Match
```

I have tried variously...

```
[\-*](.+?)(\s+\(show (.+)\))?
    Terminates early and only captures 1 char of match 1

[\-*](.+)(\s+\(show (.+)\))?
    Terminates late and captures all of the text as match 1 including `(show....`

[\-*](.+)(\s+\(show (.+)\)$)?
    As above
```

I'm sure this should be really easy! I don't want to go with negating `(show` within Match 1 - as I would like to permit this eg `-Hello (show a) (show b)` where Match 1 is `Hello (show a)` and Match 2 is `(show b)` (or just `b`)

Comment: Why `-Whatever` gives a match and `+Hello` doesn't?

Comment: Try adding the end-of-line to your 2nd attempt: `[\-*](.+)(\s+\(show (.+)\))?$` (this requires MultiLine option). I suspect adding the start-of-line `^` will do the same trick.

Comment: @M42 because whatever precedes with `-` but hello precedes with +

Comment: @M42 His requirements are to only capture lines starting with either `-` or `*`. He just gave an example of a non-capturing string.

Comment: @M42 - Yorye has it right - string must start `-` or `*`

Comment: @YoryeNathan Moving start and end anchors inside or outside capturing group appears to make little difference

Comment: Only way I have found is to negate `(` in Match 1 and insist on Match 1 ending with non whitespace eg `[\-*](([^(])+?[^ ])(\s+\(show (.+)\))?$` - and @YoryeNathan - this does use `$` outside of the parenthesis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
^[-*](.*?)(?: \(show\s*([^)]*)\)|$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kL0fA7/1)

Comment: This is perfect. It uses look-ahead, which for some reason I never remember the syntax of.

Comment: @YoryeNathan The `(?:...)` is a non-capture group, not a look-ahead. Just fyi.

Comment: @skamazin Oh, right. Don't we need a look-ahead here, so `hi (show a) (show b)` would capture `[0] = hi (show a)` and `[1] = b`, instead of `[0] = hi` and `[1] = {a, b}`?

Comment: Congratulations! I never thought of using the `$` as part of an alternation :)